# Can we use 2 different Pixel ID on one website?

Tags: facebook, facebook-marketing-api

I have two different Facebook Ad Account. One is managed my be and other is managed by my partner. We run a same ecommerce website developed in wordpress / woocommerce. We both have our own FB Ads & Pixel Accounts.

My question is can I add 2 different pixels ID in same website ? In this way both pixel can tract the traffic in their relevant FB ads account ?

Answer (score 2):

My answer is YES @Anderson. You can add multiple pixel ID in same website, you just need to init all the pixels.

fbq('init', 'FIRST PIXEL');

fbq('init', 'SECOND PIXEL');